# Calling user defined functions in PHP eval()

Tags: php, eval

I was been doing a php testing which uses eval() function, but it seems that eval() can't call user defined functions properly.

Please see my example:

```
function equals($a,$b){  
        if ($t == $r){  
        return true;  
        }  
    else{  
                throw new Exception("expected:<".$r."> but was:<".$t.">");  
    }  
}
eval("$test = 1;");  
try{  
    echo eval("equals($test,1);");  
}  
catch (Exception $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}
```

but what I have received is always like "expected:<1> but was:<>", but if I have do an

```
echo $test;
```

I can get 1.

I have tried changing $ to \$ by following the PHP eval() Manual, but it seems to break the eval function. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

So I am a bit of stack now, can someone help me with the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Code should have lines prefixed with four spaces (hint: Ctrl+K), not right angle brackets.

Comment: I will go back and try first. Thx guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are missing `return`

```
echo eval("return equals(\"$test\",1);");
```

From PHP manual

> eval() returns NULL unless return is
>   called in the evaluated code, in which
>   case the value passed to return is
>   returned. If there is a parse error in
>   the evaluated code, eval() returns
>   FALSE and execution of the following
>   code continues normally.

[eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

avoid to use eval() as @Delan suggested.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `eval()`.

If you want to call a user-defined function, say, `derp`, with the name at runtime:

```
$functionName = 'derp';
$functionName(argument1, argument2, ...);
```

Notice how I prefixed `functionName` with `$` so I'm not calling `functionName` but rather, `derp`.

So, for your example, calling a user-defined function, `equals`:

```
$functionName = 'equals';
$functionName($test, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but the problem is that I am get string as code, so it's hard to use it in this way, as I need to do a regex to get the function name and arguments.

Comment: Very useful, I didn't know about this. I though eval was my only solution, now 'eval' is 'evil' again. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use eval, I believe the problem is that you need to escape both $ (it wasn't clear from your post if you did that). So your code would read

```
    function equals($a,$b){           
if ($t == $r){          
 return true;           
}      
 else
{                   
throw new Exception("expected:<".$r."> but was:<".$t.">");       
}  
 } 
eval("\$test = 1;");   
try{       
echo eval("equals(\$test,1);");   
}   
catch (Exception $e) {      
 echo $e->getMessage();  
 }
```

You could also use single quotes for your eval strings which do not evaluate variables. 
As others have pointed out, though, there may be better ways of doing this.

Comment: Well, the only difference avoiding `$test` interpolation would be if the string was made not at the same time as `eval()` is called with it. In that case, `$test` will be evaluated during `eval()` and not when the string is created.

Comment: Good point I didn't try leaving off the second eval. The first eval fails when I run it without the \$ in my test because you are evaling " = 1;" which is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @david PHP 5, yeah, for first eval can past, but maybe because that $test is coming from eval function, the second one is not running, but don't know how to fix it. :(

Comment: @Delan Azabani thx, I just use $test as an example, in actual work is not $test.

Comment: @david error like : com.caucho.quercus.parser.QuercusParseException: string::1: unknown lexeme:\ instring::0: equals(\$a,1); I forget to mention that it is in quercus, but I think it quite similar to PHP. Besides that I have tried eval("equals(2,1);"), it works.

Comment: While it may be quite similar, in this case it seems to be different. Is the $a and $b in the function declaration a typo since you use $t and $r in the body? Perhaps an issue with Quercus's implementation of eval.

Comment: @david, so you have tried in PHP? sorry, $a,$b was a typo error. I would recheck my code and see if there is any error.