# Eval expression to evaluate match(), combine , between

Tags: php, eval, logical-operators

I need to do php eval for expression for like, between, contains and `match()`.
I have done for other logical operators and its working fine.

E.g.

```
echo eval("return ('1'==1&&'en-au'!='en-us');");
```

But i have to evaluate this expression:

```
echo eval("return ('xxxx.match(xxx) != null');");
```

Which always return true. Can someone explain how to eval this type of expressions.

Comment: If you could post actual code for xxx.match(xxx), it would help.

Comment: {(EFT.match("F")) != null}  this is the actual code

Comment: Is match() an external function? And what is EFT? I don't recognize EFT.match() as php code.

Comment: In javascript we have the expression to check eval {(EFT.match("F")) != null} but in php what are all the possibilities to do like that and also for contains, like, between

Comment: Take a look at [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). You are likely looking for preg_match($EFT, "F") or something like this.

Comment: Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167961/calling-user-defined-functions-in-php-eval?rq=1) for a related question.

Comment: how do we evaluate preg_match in eval functions

Comment: But in that url they do as functions which we defined . in my case the expression is dynamic which is came from table. Also match, Contains, between are not seperate functions right? which is like we do it query operators

Answer (score 1):

For starters, here is an example of how to evaluate `preg_match()`

```
$test = "abFc";
echo eval("return preg_match('#F#', '$test');");
```

This will output: 1

The syntax be `'xxxx.match(xxx) != null'` is not valid php syntax and so you cannot use `eval()` on it directly - it needs to be valid php. In your javascript example, `xxxx` and `xxx` are variables. They need to be rewritten so they may evaluate in php. In my example, I've rewritten the statement to `eval("return (match('$xxxx', '$xxx') !== null);")`

You can write a function, pass the variable from the table and do whatever evaluation you need to do with as many comparisons and lines of code as it takes.

For example:

```
$xxxx = "abFc";
$xxx = "F";

$eval = eval("return (match('$xxxx', '$xxx') !== null);");
if ($eval) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}


function match($string, $regex){
    // match: executes a search for a match in a string. It returns an array of information or null on a mismatch.    

    preg_match_all('#' . $regex . '#', $string, $amatch);
    if(count($amatch[0]) > 0){
        return $amatch[0];
    } else {
        return null;
    }   
}
```

Also, read the warnings regarding using `eval()` You need to make sure the data you pass to it is known to be safe.

Comment: echo eval("return preg_match('#F#', '$test');"); which is worked but how can i check with logical operators ==,!= 
eval("return ('xxxx.match(xxx) != null');");     like this

Comment: I've updated the code with what I believe you are asking, translating js syntax to php with the xxxx and xxx variables and evaluating for !==. You can simply replace == for !== if desired. Comment back if I missed your question.

Comment: Please re-read my answer - I've commented on your request to evaluate  `eval("return ('xxxx.match(xxx) != null');");`  since it is not valid php syntax